# GIT install on AS/400

Tags: git, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to install on a AS/400 running V7.2.
I have install IBM I Access Client Solution and install the open source code for GIT.
I have done the following, then I had this error.

Has anyone install GIT on a AS/400 running V7.2 ?

```
qsh
cd /qsys.lib/gitbckup.lib/qrpglesrc.file
git init
/QSYS.LIB/GITBCKUP.LIB/QRPGLESRC.FILE/.git: Error 3014 occurred.    
$
```

I have found this online so far...

```
EBADNAME
3014 - The object name specified is not correct.
```

Comment: is ".git" the member name in the QRPGLESRC file?  If it is wouldn't it need .MBR to identify it properly?  Should you use all caps because you are in the QLIB file system?

Comment: additionally that cd command is probably supposed to be somewhere in the IFS, Are you getting these instructions from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

Git for PASE has been released by IBM and packaged as an RPM. You install it with `yum`, which you can issue at a Qshell command line (`QSH`) or in a PASE session (`CALL QP2TERM`, or log in via SSH):

```
yum install git
```

Or you can do the equivalent via the GUI for IBM i Access Client Solutions (ACS).

If you do not already have `yum` installed, see instructions [here](http://ibm.biz/ibmi-rpms).

Answer (score 1):

Git on IBM i only works on IFS files in the Root and QOpenSys filesystems. It does not work on files in the QSYS.LIB filesystem or other file systems like QDLS.